# AutoForm with Meteor – Check validity of entire form?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-helper

I'm trying to make some helpers in the template where my AutoForm form lives to change some elements out side of the form to reflect errors. I've tried using

```
Template.signUp.helpers
    isValid: ->
        AutoForm.getValidationContext('signUp').isValid()
```

But that just returns the following error:

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property     '_resolvedSchema' of undefined
```

Here's the template:

```
<template name="signUp">


            {{#if isValid}} do something {{/if}}

            {{#autoForm id="signUp" schema="Schemas.SignUp" type="normal"}}

                <div class="input {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='firstName'}}error{{/if}}">
                    <label for="firstName">{{data.firstName}}</label>
                    {{> afFieldInput name="firstName" type="text"}}
                </div>

                <div class="input {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='lastName'}}error{{/if}}">
                    <label for="lastName">{{data.lastName}}</label>
                    {{> afFieldInput name="lastName" type="text"}}
                </div>

                <div class="input {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='email'}}error{{/if}}">
                    <label for="email">{{data.email}}</label>
                    {{> afFieldInput name="email" type="email"}}
                </div>

                <div class="input">         
                    {{> afFieldInput name="optIn" type="boolean-checkbox"}}
                </div>


                <button type="submit" class="btn full" data-analytics='{"eventCategory":"Sign Up","eventAction":"Click","eventLabel":"{{data.submit}}"}'><span>{{data.submit}}</span></button>


            {{/autoForm}}



    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

## ****UPDATE – Found Solution****

So after lots of playing I discovered that when you're trying to validate an AutoForm outside of the AutoForm context, you should use SimpleSchema to validate.

Here's where I'm defining the schema and saving the named context (coffeescript)

```
@Schemas = {}

@Schemas.SignUp = new SimpleSchema
firstName:
    type: String
    optional: false
lastName:
    type: String
    optional: false
email:
    type: String
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    optional: false
optIn:
    type: Boolean
    label: Localization.signUp.optIn
    optional: true
    defaultValue: false

@SignUpForm = Schemas.SignUp.namedContext('signUp')
```

And here is where I'm using SimpleSchema to validate the entire form.

```
Template.signUp.helpers
    isValid: ->
        SignUpForm.isValid()
```

sds

Comment: not sure If I'm wrong didn't use autoforms a while but isn't it validated automatically

Comment: It is validated automatically – I'm just having trouble setting up a helper that monitors it.

Comment: How does it access the current form's data?